# JSON Parse Error Unexpected End of Data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

The process function is meant to define a new ajax request and then send it to the php file. When something is typed into the text box that accepts the `capital` query string, the console displays an error that says "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" Here is my function

```
  function process(state, capital) {


xmlHttp.open("_GET", "statecapitals.php?state=" + state + "&capital=" + capital, true);

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {            
        var resultJSON = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        var result = resultJSON.capital;

        if (result === 1) {
            currentScore = score + 2;
            objScore.innerHTML = currentScore;
            showState();
            console.log(currentScore);
        };


    };



};

 xmlHttp.send(null);
};
```

Comment: are you sure your `xmlHttp.responseText` is really JSON?

Comment: would you be able to give an example of actual json?  json is finicky and has to be formatted precisely in order for `JSON.parse` to behave nicely.

Comment: Valid, as in: `{name: "bob"}`? Or valid, as in: `{"name":"bob"}`?

Comment: as in the second one

Comment: GET requests have a character limit in the response. It may happen that the response is too large, then gets truncated. After that,parse command complains the JSON is invalid. How many characters are there in the response? If it's too large, a workaround would be to use a POST request.

Comment: can you please share the data your browser is receiving from `statecapitals.php` file with us?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use first

```
  console.log(xmlHttp.responseTex);
```

Just below the

```
  if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200)
```

in your code. and check the response that it is in json or it is coming with attached with any other string.

I thinks that may help you.

Thanks